# Why Recyclerview item refresh after scrolling, using Firebase Ui , Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I use Firebase-UI for showing Image and text, and only text like Cloud Firestore database, i am facing problem whenever i scrolling down and going to that item position then that item refreshed, means if my current position is on C and i go to bottom position S and go to C then that item refreshed, i dont want this, Please help me about this, My Firebase-UI getting code is below. Thank You

```
 pbProcess.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.rv_post_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        ((SimpleItemAnimator) mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator()).setSupportsChangeAnimations(false);
        //mRecyclerView.invalidate();
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        final FirebaseFirestore mLikeCommentDb=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        final Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("posts").orderBy("datetime", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                .limit(30);
        final FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Posts> response =
                new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>()
                        .setQuery(query, Posts.class)
                        .build();

        adapterPost = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Posts,PostAdapter>(response) {
            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(PostAdapter holder, int position, Posts model) {
                pbProcess.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.bindMyView(getActivity(),holder,position,model,response.getSnapshots(),
                        myContext,mLikeCommentDb);

            }

            @Override
            public PostAdapter onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup group, int i) {
                // Create a new instance of the ViewHolder, in this case we are using a custom
                // layout called R.layout.message for each item

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(group.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.custum_home_post, group, false);

                return new PostAdapter(view);
            }
        };


        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapterPost);
        adapterPost.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and Recyclerview

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv_post_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="648dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

Please Friends help me about this, Thanks in advance, I am facing this problem in my app from last six months

Comment: Have you tried to remove `mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`?

Comment: yes, but still refresh

Comment: @QutbuddinBohra have you solved the problem? I faced this problem too

Comment: no, i did' not solved this yed, if you found please help me also,thanks